# Go to next object in For-Each loop if condition is false

Tags: function, powershell, foreach, active-directory

This is my first post. I usually come across this site when finding other questions or answers, and it's been really helpful. However, I seem to cannot find an answer for this. If I did something wrong, please let me know. Disclaimer: I am still learning PowerShell, so any constructive criticsm would be good as well.

I was tasked to check for members in an AD group. After doing some researching, I figured out the best way to make it as easy as possible. I did some further digging and found out that the ForEach loop is the best way to accept multiple entries.

So the whole point of this is to use et-ADPrincipalGroupMembership to check the what groups the user is in. I have an if statement to check to see if they are even in AD. I can verify that this works just fine. However, when I do multiple users (i.e. user1, user2, user3) it will stop on the first user who is NOT in AD and stop the function altogether.

However, if I feed contents through a file using Get-Content, then it works as attended. Any non-AD users will be caught, and the correct error will show.

Here are some examples (cltest & bcltest are real AD accounts):

```
PS C:\scripts> Get-Hscaccess cltest, cltest123, bcltest, bcltest123 
CLTEST is NOT in HSCACCESS 
CLTEST123 does not exist in AD
```

If I run the same names in a text file, I get this:

```
PS C:\scripts> gc .\hsca.txt | Get-Hscaccess  
CLTEST is NOT in HSCACCESS  
CLTEST123 does not exist in AD 
BCLTEST is NOT in HSCACCESS
BCLTEST123 does not exist in AD
```

here are the contets of the text file:

```
cltest 
cltest123 
bcltest 
bcltest123
```

I tried continue, return, break...it just stops the script, instead of going in the next object and checking through the statements again. Actually using continue goes through the next if statements, but it will fail since the user is not in AD. I hope I am making sense of what I am trying to accomplish here.

I realized that I am using $user/$users backwards. It was just $user before I realize I could have multiple input. Nothing really major though, and I can fix it when I finalize this script.

So, hopefully I explained everything, and gave examples. If I am missing something let me know. I know everyone does not have access to AD, but if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Also, I know BEGIN, PROCESS, and END is not needed, but it is the way I learned how to do this function. Also this function is in a .psm1 file, and is part of other functions in a module.

Here is the full function:

```
function Get-Hscaccess {
    param (
        [string[]]$user
    )
    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
        if ($_ -ne $null) {
            $user = $_
        }
        foreach ($users in $user) {
            $usrOBJ = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(SAMAccountName=$users)"
            if ($usrOBJ -eq $null) {
                Write-Host "$($users.ToUpper()) does not exist in AD" 
                return
            }
            $memGroups = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)
            if ($memGroups.Contains("HSCACCESS")) {
                Write-Host "$($users.ToUpper()) is in HSCACCESS"
            } 
            else {
                Write-Host "$($users.ToUpper()) is NOT in HSCACCESS"
            }
        } #end of foreach
    }   
    END {} 
}
```

Comment: The `return` after a failed lookup is causing PowerShell to exit the function.  When you pass all items as a single array, that stops it from processing any more items.  If you pass the items through the pipeline, your function is called separately for each user, so continues with the next one after one fails.  Rather than returning after a fail, try removing the `return` and putting the rest of the processing in an `else` block after your `if ($usrOBJ -eq $null){…}`, so it will only be processed if the user exits, otherwise skipped and the `foreach` moves onto the next user.

Comment: Replacing `return` with `continue` should actually do what you want AFAICS.

Comment: @boxdog I'm not sure why I didn't think of that..however it did not work. After I put the bottom code in an else block, I tested with return, continue, and finally nothing. The function will always stop after the first user is detected that it is not in AD.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers As stated in my OP, continue will go through the follow IF statements, and if a user is not in AD it will throw errors.

Comment: @Herc08 *As stated in my OP, continue will go through the follow IF statements* No, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your script and logic.

```
function Get-Hscaccess {
    param (
        [string[]]$users #The singular name was bothering my OCD.
    )

    if ($_)
    {
        foreach ($user in $users)
        {
            $usrOBJ = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(SAMAccountName=$user)" -erroraction Continue

            if ($usrOBJ -eq $null)
            {
                Write-Host "$($user.ToUpper()) does not exist in AD"
            }
            else
            {
                $memGroups = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)
                if ($memGroups.Contains("HSCACCESS"))
                {
                    Write-Host "$($user.ToUpper()) is in HSCACCESS"
                } 
                else
                {
                    Write-Host "$($user.ToUpper()) is NOT in HSCACCESS"
                }
            }
        } #end of foreach
    }   
}
```